# Difference between *argv++ and *argv-- when reaching the limit

Tags: c

could someone explain why

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  while (* argv) 
    puts(* argv++);
  return 0 ;
}
```

is legal, and

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  argv += argc - 1;
  while (* argv) 
    puts(* argv--);
  return 0 ;
}
```

isn't?
In both cases the 'crement inside the while loop will point outside of the bounds of argv. Why is it legal to point to an imaginary higher index, and not to an imaginary lower index?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the C standard says you can form a pointer to one past the end of an array, and it will still compare properly to pointers into the array (though you can't dereference it).

The standard does not say anything of the sort for a pointer to an address before the beginning of an array -- even forming such a pointer gives undefined behavior.

Comment: Not really. `argv[argc]` is guaranteed to evaluate to a null pointer.

Comment: @ouah In this particular case, yes, but Jerry Coffin caught the - general - essence.

Comment: @ouah: Yes, but `argv[-1]` isn't guaranteed to...well, anything.

Comment: @H2CO3 The thing is here we are not to one past the array. `argv` has `argc + 1` elements.

Comment: @ouah I know that, all I'm saying is that the one-past-the-array case is correctly explained in here.

Comment: I guess this comes down to one simple question: do you answer the question he actually asked (which specifies one past end) or the example he used (which doesn't actually demonstrate going past the end). I chose to answer the question, and ignore the (IMO, minor) detail that the example doesn't show quite what it purports to.

Comment: I'd say the question he asked is specifically relative to the argv case, as from the title and the example. The error comes from assuming that argc is the dimension of argv.

Answer (score 0):

Loop semantics and half-open intervals. The idiomatic way for iterating through an array or list of objects pointed to by a pointer is:

```
for (T *p = array; p < array + count; p++)
```

Here, `p` ends up being out-of-bounds (off by one, pointing one past the end of the array), so it's (not only conceptually) useful to require this not to invoke undefined behavior (the Standard actually imposes this requirement).

Comment: If I remember correctly you can iterate one item off the end of the array without invoking undefined behavior, as long as you don't access that item. I'd double-check the standard on that, though.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, that's correct, that's what I'm trying to say in this answer.

Comment: Ah ok, the double negations confused me. Disregard my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

The standard forces `argv[argc]` to be equal to `NULL`, so dereferencing argv when it's been incremented `argc` times is legal.

On the other hand nothing is defined about the address preceding `argv`, so `argv - 1` could be anything.

Note that argv is the only array of strings guaranteed to behave this way, as far as I know.

From the standard:

5.1.2.2.1 Program Startup

> If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following costraints:
>
> argv[argc] shall be a null pointer

Answer (score 0):

`argv++` or `++argv` as it is const pointer.

If you take a simple array like `char* arr[10]` and try `arr++` it will give error